# Not able to access SOAP webservice in Xamarin

Tags: web-services, soap, xamarin.forms

I'm working with SOAP webservice for that i'm referring Xamarin.forms samples(webservice) i.e 
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoASMX

But in "Data" folder there is no class which implements "ISoapService.cs" interface. I guess "SoapService.cs" class is missing in TodoASMX project.

can anyone provide me code to access SOAP service or else give me any reference sites which have detail process to access SOAP sevices.

Comment: Both the iOS and Droid projects have a SoapService.cs, which implements the ISoapService from the PCL project.